# Make Chatter Post Required or Reminder for Chatter post when status field = x

Tags: lightning, chatter

Is this possible?

Can I also create a conditional render using Lightning components to show up when status value = xyz?

Expected behavior - when status = xyz, either require user to enter chatter note or remind user to enter chatter note or create a conditional rendering (text box) using lightning component that then posts to chatter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "**[set component visibility](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iZTdQAM)**" feature to display a rich text area with a reminder in it, and place it right above a (potentially also conditionally-rendered) Chatter publish component.

In the example below I've set a rich text area component to display a message, "don't forget to post to Chatter," when the "Delivery Location" field's value equals "Customer facility."

[image]